# SQLite python - Convert value into variable

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sum

I have a table that has a column with different numbers in it. So it looks like

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| John | 22 |
| Max | 28 |
| Debbie | 22 |
| John | 21 |
| John | 52 |

How can I add up the Number column and return it to a variable

What I have now, will the number for each row matching the name, but it returns it like this: [(22),(21),(52)]

Ideally, I'd like to be able to search with select, and return total into an int variable.

```
  def get_num():
            with conn:
                c.execute("SELECT Number FROM table WHERE name=John")
                x = (c.fetchall())

                return x

        print(get_num())
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the SQL `SUM` function.

```
c.execute("SELECT SUM(Number) FROM table WHERE name='John'")
return c.fetchone()[0]
```